# Contact form 7 ajax goal tracking

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-analytics, contact-form-7

I've setup goal tracking on my site to track a contact form submission on ajax submission, I'm pretty sure I've done the on send ok right, but I must be missing something.

Here is my goal tracking:

```
Category: PPCForm
Action: Sent
Label: ppc
Value: =100
```

and here is my on sent ok:

```
on_sent_ok: "ga('send' , 'event' , 'PPCForm' , 'sent ', 'ppc' , 100);"
```

and i've made sure i have the correct analytics code in the header...

```
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-code-here', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
```

But when ever I do a submit on the form, my goal count doesn't increase, the event increases and i can see that the event has happened and the form has been submitted but the form goal just doesn't increase.

Have i done something wrong? I've searched past page 1 of google and not seen anyone else with this problem, all of my other forms seem to be working correctly. and showing goals met, but just not this one.

If anyone can help that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks as though this is correct, however it takes a few hours for the number of goals to show - the best thing to do is to go onto live tracking and see live conversions.

I was looking in the wrong place in google analytics for the results of the form. Hope this helps anyone else who might think their contact form is broken.